# c# Datagridview values print to differents printer

Tags: c#

I have two printers (Printer 1, Printer 2).When I press the button, I want to print the lines written on printer 1 in printer 1, and the lines written on printer 2 on a printer called printer 2. I would be glad if you could help

[image: My table and form picture]

Comment: What do you mean by... _"I want it to appear on the printed printer opposite."_

Comment: I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: sorry but i use google translate :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the last value of the array the code just like this

```
int index = array.Length - 1;
if(array[index].printer == "Printer1") {
  array[index].printer = "Printer2");
} else {
  array[index].printer = "Printer1";
}
```